# How do I access Vite configuration from code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, vite

Inside `vite.config.ts`, I have:

```
export default defineConfig({
  base: '',
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    open: true,
    port: 3000,
  },
});
```

Is it possible to access these values, especially the port number, from code? Or perhaps it's better to set these through easily accessible environment variables instead?

Comment: FYI in client-side code environment variables _aren't_ easily accessible and have to be injected at build time. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try by using an environment variables in a .env file or right in your vite.config.ts. Like this:

In your .env file, just add:

VITE_PORT=3000

```
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    open: true,
    port: 3000,
  },
  define: {
    __VITE_PORT__: JSON.stringify(process.env.VITE_PORT || 3000),
  },
});
```